# What's the difference between parallel_for_each and parallel_for in MSVC's Concurrency Runtime?

Tags: c++, concurrency, multicore, concurrent-programming, visual-studio-2010

`parallel_for_each` is of the form:

```
Concurrency::parallel_for_each(start_iterator, end_iterator, function_object);
```

but `parallel_for` is also of the similar form:

```
Concurrency::parallel_for(start_value, end_value, function_object);
```

so what is the difference between `Concurrency::parallel_for` and `Concurrency::parallel_for_each` algorithms used in programming for multiple cores?

Comment: You can think of `parallel_for(i, j, f)` being equivalent to: `parallel_for_each(boost::make_counting_iterator(i), boost::make_counting_iterator(j), f)`.

Comment: For those wondering, he's referring to [MSVC's Concurrency Runtime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504870.aspx).

Comment: im sorry, but what does "boost" mean? is it some kind of library?

Comment: [Yes](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/iterator/doc/counting_iterator.html).

Answer (score 7):

I don't know what library you're talking about, but it looks like this one takes iterators:

```
Concurrency::parallel_for_each(start_iterator, end_iterator, function_object);
```

And likely has the same effect as this (although not necessarily in the same order):

```
for(sometype i = start_iterator; i != end_iterator; ++i) {
    function_object(*i);
}
```

For example:

```
void do_stuff(int x) { /* ... */ }
vector<int> things;
// presumably calls do_stuff() for each thing in things
Concurrency::parallel_for_each(things.begin(), things.end(), do_stuff);
```

The other one takes values, so most likely it has a similar effect to this (but again, no guaranteed order):

```
for(sometype i = start_value; i != end_value; ++i) {
    function_object(i);
}
```

Try running this:

```
void print_value(int value) {
    cout << value << endl;
}

int main() {
    // My guess is that this will print 0 ... 9 (not necessarily in order)
    Concurrency::parallel_for(0, 10, print_value);
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: You can find confirmation of these behaviors in the [Parallel Algorithm references](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470426.aspx).

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Right, fixed.